# Test-Path for files newer than XX minutes ago

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this:

```
$now = get-date
Test-Path -NewerThan $now.AddMinutes(-130) 'D:\FileFolderLocation\*' |
  Out-File 'D:\OutputFolderLocation\checker.txt'
```

This outputs True or False if a file exists in the folder that is newer than 130 minutes ago.

Which works great with PowerShell 3.0+, but I'm running this on a server with PowerShell 2.0. Is it possible to re-write this, without using `-NewerThan`, to work with PowerShell 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Simply use `Get-ChildItem` and a `Where-Object` filter:

```
$now = Get-Date
[bool](Get-ChildItem 'D:\FileFolderLocation' |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $now.AddMinutes(-130) }) |
  Out-File 'D:\OutputFolderLocation\checker.txt'
```

Casting the result to `bool` produces `$true` or `$false` depending on whether or not a matching file was found. If you need to exclude directories add `-and -not $_.PSIsContainer` to the filter.

Comment: Hm, this worked in PS 3, but when trying to run on the server with PS 2, I get this error: 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
At D:\folder\powershellscriptname.ps1:2 char:54
+    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $now.AddMinutes <<<< (-130) {) | 
     + CategoryInfo           : INvalidOperation: (AddMinutes:String) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

This error is repeated for every file that is in the D:\FileFolderLocation folder

Comment: @Ken Of course you still need to populate `$now` before you can use that variable.

Comment: Just realized that too as I refreshed this page :)